# MYSQL Left join extremely slow on indexed columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are the 4 tables' table structure:

Calendar:

```
CREATE TABLE `calender` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HospitalID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ColorCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RecurrID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `idxHospital` (`ID`,`StaffID`,`HospitalID`,`ColorCode`,`RecurrID`,`IsActive`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4638 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

CalendarAttendee:

```
CREATE TABLE `calenderattendee` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CalenderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `StaffID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `idxCalStaffID` (`StaffID`,`CalenderID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20436 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

CallPlanStaff:

```
CREATE TABLE `callplanstaff` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Staffname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `idx_IsActive` (`Staffname`,`IsActive`),
  KEY `idx_staffName` (`Staffname`,`ID`) USING BTREE KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=100
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_name` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_email` (`email`) USING BTREE KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=100
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I'm trying to do is to fetch the calender.ID and Users.name using below query:

```
SELECT a.ID, h.name
    FROM `stjude`.`calender` a 
    left join calenderattendee e on a.ID = e.calenderID
    left join callplanstaff f on e.StaffID = f.ID
    left join users h on f.Staffname = h.email
```

The relation between those tables are:

[image]

It took about 4 seconds to fetch 13000 records which I bet it could be faster.

When I look at the tabular explain of the query, here's the result:

[image]

Why MYSQL isn't using index on callplanstaff table and users table?

Also, in my case, should I use multi index instead of multi column index?

And is there any indexes I'm missing so my query is slow?

=======================================================================

Updated:

As zedfoxus and spencer7593 recommended to change the idxCalStaffID's ordering and idx_staffname's ordering, below is the execution plan:

[image]

It took 0.063 seconds to fetch, much fewer time required, how does the ordering of the indexing affects the fetch time..?

Comment: 4 seconds to query or 4 seconds to fetch? That distinction is important. Fetch usually means fetch and display as well

Comment: @e4c5 4 seconds to fetch

Comment: well 13,000 records, fetching and displaying them might take that long. This becomes a query optimization problem if the query itself is slow. I will bet that the query itself is reasonably fast, your biggest table has only about 20k rows

Comment: How does your explain look if you switched ordering in idxCalStaffID to (calendarid, staffid) and idx_staffName to (id, staffname)?

Comment: This is sort of irrelevant, but you misspelled "calendar" everywhere. There is a word "calender" as well, but I had to look it up and found it's an obscure term meaning "a machine in which cloth or paper is pressed by rollers to glaze or smooth it." :-)

Comment: @zedfoxus I updated my post with the new explain :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the EXPLAIN report.

- `type: index` is not such a good thing. It means it's doing an "index-scan" which examines *every* element of an index. It's almost as bad as a table-scan. Notice the column `rows: 4562` and `rows: 13451`. This is the estimated number of index elements it will examine for each of those tables.
- Having *two* tables doing a index-scan is even worse. The total number of rows examined for this join is 4562 x 13451 = 61,363,462.
- `Using join buffer` is not a good thing. It's a thing the optimizer does as a consolation when it can't use an index for the join.
- `type: eqref` is a good thing. It means it's using a PRIMARY KEY index or UNIQUE KEY index, to look up exactly one row. Notice the column `rows: 1`. So at least for each of the rows from the previous join, it only does one index lookup.
- You should create an index on calenderattendee for columns (CalenderId, StaffId) in that order (@spencer7593 posted this suggestion while I was writing my post).
- By using `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` in this query, you're preventing MySQL from optimizing the order of table joins. And since your query fetches `h.name`, I infer that you really just want results where the calendar event has an attendee and the attendee has a corresponding user record. It makes no sense that you're not using an `INNER JOIN`.

Here's the EXPLAIN with the new index and the joins changed to `INNER JOIN` (though my row counts are meaningless because I didn't create test data):

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                  | key                  | key_len | ref            | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,ID_UNIQUE,idxHospital  | ID_UNIQUE            | 4       | NULL           |    1 |   100.00 | Using index           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | ref    | idxCalStaffID,CalenderID       | CalenderID           | 4       | test.a.ID      |    1 |   100.00 | Using index           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID_UNIQUE              | PRIMARY              | 4       | test.e.StaffID |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h     | NULL       | eq_ref | index_users_on_email,idx_email | index_users_on_email | 767     | func           |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

The `type: index` for the calenderattendee table has been changed to `type: ref` which means an index lookup against a non-unique index. And the note about `Using join buffer` is gone.

That should run better.

---

> how does the ordering of the indexing affects the fetch time..?

Think of a telephone book, which is ordered by last name first, then by first name. This helps you look up people by last name very quickly. But it does not help you look up people by first name.

The position of columns in an index matters!

You might like my presentation *How to Design Indexes, Really*.

- Slides: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really
- Video of me presenting this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: I thought of using inner join before, but that would filter out the records which don't have "Calendarattendee" which would need to be shown on the page.

Comment: Well, at least try the proper index.

Comment: Oh I've propered the index and the performance had increased a lot

Comment: Another excellent answer, as we usually expect from Bill. +10. Good points on interpreting MySQL EXPLAIN output, and the unnecessary redundant indexes.

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Is there any indexes I'm missing so my query is slow?**

**A:** Yes. A suitable index on `calendarattendee` is missing.

---

We probably want an index on `calenderattendee` with a `calendarid` as the leading column, for example:

```
 ... ON calenderattendee (calendaid, staffid)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a situation where inner join might be a better option than a left join.

```
SELECT a.ID, h.name
    FROM `stjude`.`calender` a 
    INNER JOIN calenderattendee e on a.ID = e.calenderID
    INNER JOIN callplanstaff f on e.StaffID = f.ID
    INNER JOIN users h on f.Staffname = h.email
```

Then let's get onto the indexes. The Calendar table has

```
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
```

The second one, ID_UNIQUE is redundant. A Primary key is a unique index. Having too many indexes slows down insert/update/delete operations.

Then the users table has

```
UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_name` (`name`),
KEY `idx_email` (`email`) USING BTREE KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=100
```

The idx_email column is redundant here. Other than that there isn't much to do by way of tweaking the indexes. Your explain shows that an index is being used on each and table.

> Why MYSQL isn't using index on callplanstaff table and users table?

Your explain shows that it does. The it's using the primary key and the index_users_on_email indexes on these tables.

> Also, in my case, should I use multi index instead of multi column
>   index?

As a rule of thumb, mysql uses only one index per table. So a multi column index is the way to go rather than having multiple indexes.

> And is there any indexes I'm missing so my query is slow?

As I mentioned in the comments you are fetching (and probably displaying) 13,000 records. That's where your bottleneck maybe.